# My requests to BD are mysteriously multiplied: Python and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**CONTEXT.** Python 3.9.1, Flask 2.0.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1, SQLAlchemy==1.4.25

**WHAT I WANT TO DO.** Delete records from MySQL database

**PROBLEM.** I have a view that lists my blogposts in a [datatables](https://datatables.net/) (the datatable works with Ajax). Each row contains a button to delete the record. The records that I try to delete are deleted ok from the DB. The problem is that each deletion executes as many requests to the DB as I have tried to delete records. That is, the 1st deletion executes 1 request, the 2nd executes 2 requests, the 3rd executes 3 requests, etc. After about 10 deleted posts the error appears: `SQLAlchemyError: Exception SQLAlchemyError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached`. The console shows this according to the example I give when I have deleted registers 48, 49 and 50:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:43] "POST /backend/blog/delete/48 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:47] "POST /backend/blog/delete/49 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:47] "POST /backend/blog/delete/49 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2021 20:57:51] "POST /backend/blog/delete/50 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**WHAT AM I DOING.**

*Controller* (I did not delete code here, as I have it)

```
@blueprint.route('/delete/<id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete(id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        response = {
            'status': False,
            'toastrMsg': '...',
            'toastrType': 'danger',
            'toastrTitle': '...'
        }
        postExist = Blog.getById(id)
        blogpostTitle = '?'
        boolvar = bool(postExist)

        if boolvar:
            blogpostTitle = postExist.title
            Blog.delete(id)
            response = {
                'status': True,
                'toastrMsg': 'Deleted post ('+blogpostTitle+' with ID: '+id+')',
                'toastrType': 'success',
                'toastrTitle': '¡Yeeeha!'
            }
        else:
            response = {
                'status': False,
                'toastrMsg': 'Unable to delete blogpost, as the post (ID: '+ id +') could not be retrieved from the database',
                'toastrType': 'danger',
                'toastrTitle': '¡Ooops!'
            }
        return jsonify(response)
```

*Model*

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sessionDB = scoped_session(session_factory)

class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blog'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    content = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now(), onupdate=datetime.now())

    # This method is responsible for recovering the data that goes to the datatables
    def collect_data_serverside(self, request):
        DATA = []
        query = sessionDB.query(User, Blog).filter(User.id==Blog.author_id)
        for u, b in query.all():
            DATA.append({'A': b.id, 'B': u.nombre, 'C': b.title, 'D': b.created_at})
        columns = table_schemas.BLOG
        return ServerSideTable(request, DATA, columns, True, True, 'backend.blog', 'C', 'table_blogposts').output_result()

    def delete(id):
        sessionDB.query(Blog).filter(Blog.id == id).delete()
        sessionDB.commit()
        sessionDB.close()
        sessionDB.remove()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**HOW I TRIED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM.**

I thought maybe there could be an improvement if I changed the way I delete blogposts. I tried to manage the database differently, so I declared: `db = SQLAlchemy()` in my main **init**.py, above `create_app()` (the structure of my project is the same as the [Official flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/)), and then I used that instance of SQLAlchemy in my `delete()` method:

```
db.create_all(app=create_app())
db.session.query(Blog).filter_by(id=id).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

It did not work. The problem persists.

Comment: I didn't review super thoroughly, but it seems like you're passing the *Blog's* ID in this line: `Blog.delete(id)` which would seem to me to delete all posts within that particular blog.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed two things:

The console continues to show one request on the first delete, two requests on the second, and so on.

Secondly, I have solved the most important thing, that is, that the application does not throw the error: `QueuePool limit of size <x> overflow <y> reached, connection timed out, timeout <z>`. I have 2 models: user.py and blog.py. In both I was declaring the session to the DB:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sessionDB = scoped_session(session_factory)
```

I naturally assumed that I should put this code in each model. So I ventured to remove this code from blog.py and leave only the code from user.py. And I realized that the application was still working! But that was not all: I was able to delete as many posts as I wanted without the error jumping again.